# generate consecutive numbers in php

Tags: php, sql

My table call a series of products. With php I generate a row to insert a product. Every time I create a new row it should generate consecutive numbers for each products inserted.

Comment: Please add some more examples and fix your question.

Comment: do you mean to generate an ID for your table?

Comment: You need to use Auto_increment attribute on the column if table is in MySql or use identity if using SQL server.

Comment: It is that when entering multiple products in the row that purchase is generated and sent to box stops there , then make another purchase consecutive start from 1 is not what I mean

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to generate the ID using PHP, you can set the auto_increment option for the ID field on your database, it will assign the ID automaitcally

You can find better examples and more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: explain better to purchase some products these are added to the database I want to generate a row but upon purchase and choose other products consecutive start 1 and the first products are chosen to remain intact .

Comment: I dont undertand so well your comment, could you give me an example?

Comment: can be done in javascript jPrompt only accept numbers?